# How to sort array in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

I have an array resulted from external API. I want to sort this array using ASC format, but when test it on my function, The sorted result is same like my array data. It is not sorted. I am using Laravel 5.7 to do this.

This is my function :

```
public function sortData(){

    $arrayData = [
        {"id":"950328","type":"CMATYPE ","num":"10"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM007","num":"20"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM021B ","num":"30"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM047","num":"40"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM-MMFGF","num":"50"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM152","num":"60"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM179 ","num":"70"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM029A","num":"80"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM033C ","num":"90"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM033E","num":"100"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM001 ","num":"110"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM012","num":"120"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM202 ","num":"130"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM203","num":"140"},  
        {"id":"950328","type":"CM205 ","num":"150"},
        {"id":"950328","type":"CASE","num":"160"}
    ];

    foreach ($arrayData as $key => $value){
        $sorted = collect($value)->sortBy($value['type']);
        echo "Data From Server : ".$sorted['type']."\n";
    }
}
```

This is the result :

```
Data From Server : CM007
Data From Server : CM021B
Data From Server : CM047
Data From Server : CM-MMFGF
Data From Server : CM152
Data From Server : CM179
Data From Server : CM029A
Data From Server : CM033C
Data From Server : CM033E
Data From Server : CM001
Data From Server : CM012
Data From Server : CM202
Data From Server : CM203
Data From Server : CM205
Data From Server : CASE
```

Something wrong with my function? How to fix this?

Comment: Please correct your code first. Your `$arrayData` is not in PHP syntax.

Comment: use `sortBy($value['type'], SORT_NATURAL, true)`

Comment: @RahmatEffendi Show your expected result. Also, are those json strings or actual PHP arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [sort by](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby) in laravel

```
$sorted = collect($arrayData)->sortBy('type');
```